# Play2 and Scala - Static files and I18 messages in my JS files

Tags: javascript, scala, internationalization, routes, playframework-2.1

When posting a form in my web app I perform a couple of checks in javascript before validating the form in the backend. The js validation is dependent upon I18 messages and images.
If this was a scala template I would of course use **@Messages** and **@routes.Assets.at** but I don't want to mix the two(scala template and .js file).

E.g I have this check in my js file where currently the image routes is hardcoded:

```
$("form input[type=submit]").click(function (e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var email = $("#username");
            var emailPattern = /^([0-9a-zA-Z]([-\.\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z])*@([0-9a-zA-Z][-\w]*[0-9a-zA-Z]\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,9})$/;

            if (email.val() == "") {
                email.css("background-image", "url('/assets/images/general/input-row-red.jpg')");
                return e.preventDefault();
            } else {
                email.css("background-image", "url(/images/general/inputTextBg.png)");
            }
    });
```

I have tried to prepare the js files with the messages they need like this:

**.js file:**

```
/* Prepare messages*/
var messages = "";

$.getJSON("/messages/source", {
        "keys": "sms.form.login.hide,sms.form.login"},
    function (data) {
        messages = data.messages;
    });
```

**MessageSource controller:**

```
object MessageSource extends Controller {

  def getMessages(keys : String) = Action { request =>
     if(keys.isEmpty) {
       BadRequest(Json.obj("status" -> "KO", "message" -> "key plix!"))
     }
     else {
       var js = Map.empty[String, String]
       for (k <- keys.split(",")) {
         js = js + (k -> Messages(k))
       }
       Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "OK", "messages" -> js))
     }
  }
}
```

But I don't feel that this is the best solution. I have looked at `http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaRouting` but I can't figure it out.
Maybe you have some nice solution for me?

Comment: We use a similar style where `JavaScript` makes a call to the server to get it's configuration. In our case `JSONP` style using `require-js`. ([config method in controller](https://github.com/Rhinofly/kerst2012/blob/master/site/app/controllers/Application.scala#L87), [js configuration](https://github.com/Rhinofly/kerst2012/blob/master/site/app/assets/javascripts/JsConfiguration.scala), [config dependency](https://github.com/Rhinofly/kerst2012/blob/master/site/app/assets/javascripts/config.js#L16))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this way?

**jsfile:**

```
@scripts = {
        <script type="text/javascript" src="@routes.Application.javascriptRoutes"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        jsRoutes.controllers.Application.messages("admin.venue.1,admin.venue.2,admin.venue.3" ).ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.messages);

        },
            error: function () {
                console.log("error");
            }
        });
        </script>    
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
object Application extends Controller {

  def javascriptRoutes = Action {
    implicit request =>
      import routes.javascript._
      Ok(
        Routes.javascriptRouter("jsRoutes")
          (
            routes.javascript.Application.messages
          )
      ).as("text/javascript")


  }

  def messages(keys : String) = Action {
    implicit request => {
      val messages = keys.split(",").map { key =>
        key -> Messages(key)
      }.toMap

      Ok(Json.obj("status" -> "OK", "messages" -> messages))
    }
  }

}
```

**routes:**

```
# Javascript routes
GET         /javascriptRoutes                 controllers.Application.javascriptRoutes
GET         /messages                       controllers.Application.messages(keys: String)
```